# JPA EntityManager values are not persisted in database when tested using Junit

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, junit, jpa-2.0

I am using Hibernate 4 with Spring 3 and when I try to do Junit test, values are not persisted in database

In my DAO implementation class

```
@Transactional
@Repository
public class ProjectDAOImpl extends GenericDAOImpl<Project>
        implements ProjectDAO {

public void create(Project project) {
        entityManager.persist(project);
        System.out.println("val  2  -- "+project.getProjectNo());
    }

@PersistenceContext
    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }
```

and in Junit test I have

```
@TransactionConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration({"classpath:applicationContext.xml"})
@Transactional
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class) 
public class ProjectTest {

@Resource
ProjectService projectService;   

@Test
    public void createProject(){
        Project project = new Project();
        project.setProjectName("999---");
        projectService.create(project);
    }
```

I am able to see the value for this statement in console though, however record is not saved in database.

```
System.out.println("val  2  -- "+project.getProjectNo());
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By default Spring Test will rollback all transactions in a unit test causing them not to appear in the database.

You can change default setting by adding the following annotation to the test class, which will cause the transactions to be committed.

```
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback=false)
@ContextConfiguration({"classpath:applicationContext.xml"})
@Transactional
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class) 
public class ProjectTest {
    //Tests here
}
```

Comment: Oh boy, what a wonderful forum Stack Overflow is. This was just what was missing for me. Thank you so much for sharing your knowledge and thank you @user75ponic for posting the question. This has saved me so much trouble.

Answer (score 8):

Based on the fact that **@TransactionConfiguration** is deprecated since **Spring Framework 4.2** came out it's recommended to use **@Rollback**.

```
@Rollback(false)
@ContextConfiguration({"classpath:applicationContext.xml"})
@Transactional
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class) 
public class ProjectTest {
    //Tests here
}
```